# Can modeh ani be recited before the person dress up?

Tags: tefilla

If a person wake up early everyday but have a little time before he go to work. And I understood from a website that praying Modeh Ani after eating is disrespectful toward the Almighty.

Can I recite it before dressing up for work ?

Comment: I mistakenly related this question to the book "To Be a Jew" while I found this descrption in a website only. My apologize !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. 
The custom among many Jews, is to say it right when you wake up.

Quote from Siddur harav (loosely translated): It's good to get into the habit of saying modeh ani right when to wake up and through this you'll remember G-d who stands over you and you'll get up quickly.

So if you wake up before getting dressed, then yes, you can say it before getting dressed :)

Comment: Maybe the Siddur harav was only referring to people who don't sleep nude?

Comment: @DoubleAA Could be, but it's not a berachah or anything like that, or else you'd first need to wash negel vasser. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this what most Jews do?